# make the table td flexible using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a demo. I need some help regarding the flexibility of the table cells.

I am having some cells for table in which their widths should be fixed.

But the cells consists of labels which can have a long text or a short text.

based on this labels the tables cells should works flexibly. but the condition is the text should come in one line and should not wrap with the other cells text.

css;

```
td{
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>asjkdkasdhadhakdhad asdjkaskdhaksdhakdhakd askdhaskdhakdhakdjad akssdhadkhakd </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>an </label>
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NDMTH/3/

Comment: If you do not want the long label text to get wrapped to multiple lines, add `white-space:pre` for the labels. If you want only a certain amount of text to be displayed, additionally give them a `max-width` and use `text-overflow` to control how exactly the clipping of the text should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, use the property `min-width` instead of `width`:

```
td{
    min-width:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

And `white-space:nowrap` on `label` ([MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space)):

```
label{
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

[Working example on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/NDMTH/4/)

Comment: hai but the label text is occupying two lines. it should be in single line.

Comment: @user1853128 I was updating my answer to fit this requirement